# Cast Iron - Enamelled - Season or not?

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

I have one of these - http://www.victoriasbasement.com.au/Product/Details/75766 - which I bought recently. Its an enamelled cast iron pan. I've been seasoning it by rubbing it down in oil and putting it in the oven. The seasoning doesn't seem to last very long though. Should I not be seasoning it because its enamelled? If so, should I try and get a non-enamelled cast iron pan if I want something with better non stick properties?

Comment: Plenty of cast iron seasoning advice already on SA. Basically you need to do more of it!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to season an enameled pot.  The enamel serves much of the same purpose as building up a layer of seasoning.

Although the enamel won't ever be quite as slick as seasoned cast iron, it protects the vessel from rust, makes food less likely to stick (with a little help from some oil), and easier to clean up afterwards.

Comment: Look at the links picture! only the outside is enamelled. It will need seasoning just like any cast iron pan

Comment: @TFD : we've gone over this on other questions -- just because the inside is black doesn't mean that it's bare iron that needs to be seasoned.  I can't verify on that particular brand, but there are brands that enamel the inside in black, and even some that teflon coat the inside.  (Le Creuset has a few that are teflon coated)

Comment: Your eyes must be better then mine. Either way your answer should then really ask what is interior surface then? A blanket statement isn't helpful without information