# Should an enameled cast iron pan be seasoned?

Tags: cast-iron, frying-pan, seasoning-pans

Should I season my Michael Symon Home enameled cast iron frying pan?

Comment: It comes pre-seasoned, but just about everything I cook, sticks.

Comment: you don't typically season enameled cast iron, unless it's only enameled on the outside.  Were there instructions that came with it?

Comment: No instructions about seasoning at all; just to say that it is already seasoned.

Comment: Well enamel cast iron aren't as non-stick as well seasoned frying pans.

Comment: Can I season my enameled cast iron fry pan; will I hurt it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast Iron - Enamelled - Season or not?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56928/cast-iron-enamelled-season-or-not)

Comment: Good catch @moscafj!  I was sure there was one but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No, you cannot season enameled cast iron cookware.

Enamel does not take seasoning in the same sense as cast iron or carbon steel.

I don't know if seasoning would *hurt" the pan, but I've never heard of **anyone** seasoning their enamel cookware. So if you do try it though, let us know how it goes.

If you’re gonna season, just buy cast iron and save a lot of money.

Answer (score 8):

As per @Joe's comment you don't season enameled cookware. I did a Google search on this cookware. Per the specs, the inside is enameled. And nowhere in the description or specs could I find any reference to the pan being pre-seasoned. (Which makes sense for an enameled pan.) Additionally, I found nothing claiming that the pan is non-stick.

Here's a link to the [use and care insert](https://img.hsni.com/images/content/f4be8cf7-e9cf-48f4-8cbf-92654b28a426Michael_Symon_Use_&_Care_Card_Final_Outlined_(7Nov2017)-01.jpg) that clearly states there is no reason to season the pan.

Additional info: Here's a link to an [HSN page](https://www.hsn.com/products/symon-home-12-enameled-cast-iron-frypan/8576075#) featuring one of these pans. Product description, features, and specs can be viewed there, along with a picture and a link to the use and care information.

Answer (score 0):

I DID season my Dutch Oven. Not the inside (enameled) though. The rim of the oven is a thin strip of cast iron. The rim of the lid is also cast iron. I didn’t see where it would hurt to do so. I looked on YouTube and a couple of people did show you how to do so with Enameled Cast Iron Dutch Ovens. With your fingertip just rub oil around the trim which again is cast iron. Rub in really good … wipe off excess that has run down oven. Put in oven upside down turn to 350 Fahrenheit leave in one hour turn off oven. Let sit in oven until cooled off.